# Cómo crear funciones con múltiples salidas en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, matlab

Estoy trabajando con un código de MATLAB y resulta que me hallé con una serie de métodos( y funciones) que he tratado de pasarlos a la sintaxis de Python.
Cómo debo interpretar en Python esta sintaxis `function [y1,...,yN] = myfun(x1,...,xM)`

Función hecha en MATLAB:

```
function [stmat,utim,costmat,dhdu,Jiter,H]...
=optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol(tvec,st0,b)
% This function computes the optimal control and
% the corresponding states and the co-states.
% Method of Steepest Descent is used for this.
% n=no. of sections
nt=length(tvec) ; n=length(st0) ; n=n/2 ;
utim=0.1*ones(nt,n) ; % assume control
% forward integration for states
stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b) ;
rho=stmat(:,1:n); rhof=rho(end,:);
% time increment for simulation
dt=tvec(2)-tvec(1) ;
% cost function for the simulation
J=sum(sum(rho.^2+utim.^2,2)*dt)+sum(rhof.^2);
% iter=no of control update iterations
% Jiter=vector of iteration cost values
iter=1 ; Jiter(iter)=J ;
% convergence:
% test=0 => not occured test=1 => occured.
test=0 ;
% tolerences
tol1=10^-4 ; tol2=10^-6 ;
% iterations for control and cost till
% convergence occurs
while test==0 % check for convergence
iter=iter+1 ;
stf=stmat(end,:)' ; rhof=stf(1:n) ;
costf=[2*rhof;zeros(n,1)] ;
% backward integration for co-states
costmat=bkcostinteg(tvec,stmat,costf,b) ;
% calculation dhdu at all time
dhdu=2*utim+costmat(:,n+1:2*n) ;
% "cntrl_update" updates the control and state
% for the next iteration
[stmat,utim,J,test]=...
    cntrl_update(tvec,stmat,utim,dhdu,b,tol1,tol2) ;
% Jiter(iter)=value of the cost function at the
% current iteration.
Jiter(iter)=J ;
end
rho=stmat(:,1:n) ; vf=stmat(:,n+1:2*n) ;
p=costmat(:,1:n) ; pvf=costmat(:,n+1:2*n) ;
% Computation for hamiltonian
H=zeros(nt,1) ;
for i=1:1:n
H=H+rho(:,i).^2+utim(:,i).^2+p(:,i)...
.*(-rho(:,i).*(1-rho(:,i))*b(i).*vf(:,i)) ;
H=H+pvf(:,i).*utim(:,i) ;
if i>=2
H=H+p(:,i).*(rho(:,i-1).*(1-rho(:,i-1))...
*b(i).*vf(:,i-1)) ;
end
end
end
```

Lo que yo hice en Python:

```
#Creacion de la función optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol
def optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol(tvec,st0,b):
    # Esta función calcula el control óptimo y
    # los estados correspondientes y los co-estados.
    # Método de descenso más pronunciado se utiliza para esto.
    # n = N°. de secciones
    nt=len(tvec)
    n=len(st0)
    n=n/2
    utim=0.1*np.ones((nt,n))#% asume la integración de
    #control de avance para los estados
    stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b)
    rho=stmat[:,0:n+1]
    rhof=rho[end,:]
    #tiempo de incremento para la simulación
    dt=tvec[1]-tvec[0]
    #funcion de costo para la simulación
    #axis=1 => horizontal
    #axis=0 => vertical
    J=np.sum(np.sum(rho**2 + utim**2,axis=1)*dt)+np.sum(rhof**2)
    #itera= número de iteraciones de actualización de control
    #Jiter= vector de valores de costo de iteración
    itera=1
    Jiter[itera]=J
    #convergencia
    #test=0 => no ocurre test=1 => ocurre
    test=0
    #Tolerancias
    tol=10**(-4)
    tol2=10**(-6)
    #iteraciones para control y costo hasta
    #que ocurre la convergencia
    while (test==0):#para chequear la convergencia
        itera=itera+1
        stf=(stmat[-1:,]).transpose()
        rhof=stf[0:n+1]
        v=[[[2*rhof]],np.zeros(n)]
        costf=np.array(v)
        #integración hacia atrás para co-estados
        costmat=bkcostinteg(tvec,stmat,costf,b)
        #calculo dhdu de todo el tiempo
        dhdu=2*utim+costmat[:,n+2:2*(n+1)]
        #"cntrl_update" actualiza el control y el estado
        #para la próxima iteración
        metod2=cntrl_update(tvec,stmat,utim,dhdu,b,tol,tol2)
        Jiter[iter]=J
    rho=stmat[:,0:n+1]
    vf=stmat[:,n+2:2*(n+1)]
    p=costmat[:,0:n+1]
    pvf=costmat[:,n+2:2*(n+1)]
    #cálculo del hamiltoniano
    H=np.zeros(int(nt))
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        H=H+rho[:,i]**2 + utim[:,i]**2 +p[:,i]*(-rho[:,i]*(1-rho[:,i])*b[i]*vf[:,i])
        H=H+pvf[:,i]*utim[:,i]
        if i>=2:
            H=H+p[:,i]*(rho[:,i-1]*(1-rho[:,i-1])*b[i]*vf[:,i-1])
```

Comment: Por qué no simplemente mandas una lista como parámetro? `def myFun(listaDeParametros)` y la llamás `myFun([x1, x2, x3, x4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python debes usar la palabra reservada `return` para indicar de forma explícita que debe retornar la función (en MATLAB `return` simplemente se usa para indicar en que momento debe retornar la función (si no queremos que se ejecute al completo), pero no para indicar que debe retornar). Por defecto todas las funciones/métodos retornan `None` si no se indica lo contrario mediante `return`.

Partiendo de un ejemplo más simple en MATLAB, por ejemplo una función para transformar una coordenada cartesiana a polar:

```
function [radio, acimut] = cartesianas_a_polares(x, y)
    radio = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    acimut = atan(y / x)
    end
```

Sería llamada:

```
[r, a] = cartesianas_a_polares(5, 8)
```

En Python para reproducir el mismo comportamiento debemos hacer algo como:

```
import math

def cartesianas_a_polares(x, y):
    radio = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    acimut = math.atan(y / x)
    return radio, acimut
```

Y llamaríamos a la función con:

```
r, a = cartesianas_a_polares(5, 8)
```

`return radio, acimut` es en realidad azúcar sintáctica para `return (radio, acimut`) , es decir, lo que se retorna es una tupla con los valores de las variables:

```
>>> res = cartesianas_a_polares(5, 8)
>>> res
(9.433981132056603, 1.0121970114513341)
```

Para almacenar los valores en variables distintas basta con desempaquetar la tupla, lo cual hacemos con `r, a = cartesianas_a_polares(5, 8)`:

```
>>> r, a = cartesianas_a_polares(5, 8)
>>> r
9.433981132056603
>>> a
1.0121970114513341
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que en el momento que se llega a un estamento `return` la ejecución de la función termina. Podemos tener cualquier número de estamentos, por ejemplo:

```
def es_primo(n):

    # Si es 2 la ejecución termina y retornamos True
    if n == 2:
        return True

    # Si es menor de dos o es par la ejecución termina y retornamos False
    if n < 2 or not n % 2 :
        return False

    # Si es divisible entre cualquier entero inpar menor que el la ejecución termina y retornamos False
    for d in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if not n % d:
            return False

    # Si nada se cumple el número es primo y retornamos True    
    return True
```